# Centering a window to its parent window's center properly with PyQt5

Tags: pyqt5

I thought of a simple algorithm and implemented it like this:

```
def parentcenter(self):
    self.move(self.parent().frameGeometry().center().x() - self.frameGeometry().width()/2, self.parent().frameGeometry().center().y() - self.frameGeometry().height()/2)
```

It looks good on paper but it doesn't work properly. The child window places itself like it's placed at `self.parent().frameGeometry().center()`. I also tried to print the width and height of the child window by doing `print(self.frameGeometry().width())` to see if anything is wrong, and it sure is. The values width and height shows much less than I expected. My child window has the width value of 100 while it's filling 1/3 of the screen. My screen resolution is not something like 300x300 lol

Why do this happen? Or can I still center my child window without using the methods above?

Comment: Have you tried using a `QTimer` to call `parentcenter` after the windows have been drawn? I suspect the values you are using a prior to the window actually being given it's proper size. Try adding `QTimer.singleShot(100, self.parentcenter)` to the `__init__` method of the class.

Comment: The QTimer function didn't work but you gave me the idea to call parentcenter AFTER the windows have been drawn so I tried it out and it worked! I knew that my code was right :D Thanks a lot again!

Comment: Great, glad I could help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to three_pineapples, I have solved this problem. The only thing I did was to call `parentcenter` after the `SetupUi` at the `__init__`.